# MSMQ Disaster Recovery - How to recover message queues from a crashed machine?

Tags: disaster-recovery, msmq

How can message queues be recovered from a crashed machine, so that transactional messages can be restored on a new machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the MSMQ Service on both source and destination machines:

> net stop MSMQ

Delete the following folder on the destination machine and replace with the corresponding folder contents from the source machine:

> C:\Windows\System32\msmq

Grant access to copied folder on the destination MSMQ service:

> icacls.exe "C:\Windows\System32\msmq"  /grant "NT SERVICE\MSMQ":(F)

Configure MSMQ to ignore checkpoint files:

> Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters,
>   and then click Parameters.
>   On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
>   In the Name field, enter "LogDataCreated," and then ensure that the
>   value is set to 0.

Open the queue properties in the following location. Files are text and can be opened with notepad.

> C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage\lqs

Change the ‘Security’ field to match one from a working queue. An example is given below:

> Security=0100078... etc

Restart the MSMQ Service on the destination machine:

> net start MSMQ

**Troubleshooting:**

- Failure to write destination files: Navigate the destination subfolders, so that Explorer will prompt to allow access.
- Some messages may be duplicated, as the checkpoint files have been deleted.
- If the list of messages can be viewed but not the message contents themselves, the ‘security’ field must be changed in the queue properties.

**References:**

[Interpreting file names in the Storage directory in Microsoft Message Queue Server and in Microsoft Message Queuing](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;174307)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733512.aspx

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2012/03/msmqsecurity-descriptor-cannot-be-set.html

Comment: Make sure the new machine has the same computername as the original.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell Interesting. I'm not sure I did that. Will have to check next time.

Comment: MSMQ crashed on a POS system all the time. Deleting the content of the folder `C:\Windows\System32\msmq` did the thing.